# Where do Dory and Nemo live?

Tags: finding-dory, finding-nemo

What am I missing about "crossing the ocean" in both related movies?

In (non-direct cites):

1. "Finding Nemo" (2003) they had to "cross the ocean" to reach Sydney and find Nemo, so I assumed they lived somewhere by US west coast.
2. "Finding Dory" (2016) Dory would have to "cross the ocean" to live in California, so this suggests eastern coast of Australia or Asia in general or Japan or Oceania.

Where do Dory and Nemo live?

Comment: "Crossing the ocean" seems like a very daunting task, which could potentially lead to an amazing adventure.  Not that 1200 nautical miles doesn't sound like a lengthy journey, but it doesn't have the same impact to an 8 year old.

Comment: If I live in a little oasis in the desert, no matter which direction I travel in, I have to cross the desert to get there. Just because I "cross the desert" doesn't automatically mean that I travel from one border of the desert to the opposite border.

Comment: @Flater True, of course! But this doesn't forbid someone asking you "Where exactly do you live", right? :>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finding_Nemo#:%7E:text=Nemo%20is%20a%20young%20clownfish,in%20the%20Great%20Barrier%20Reef.) (as well as every other link when I searched), Marlin and Nemo live in an anemone in the Great Barrier Reef, Australia. The GBR is located off of the North Eastern coast of Australia. It's about 1200 nautical miles to Sydney, Australia, off the South Eastern coast. So while they don't have to cross the entire Pacific Ocean, Nemo still has quite a journey.

[image: Marlin and Nemo]
<sub>Disney Pixar's Marlin and Nemo at home (Finding Nemo)</sub>

According to [this article](https://www.slashfilm.com/finding-dory-setting/), as well as other search results, Dory lives with Nemo and Marlin in the GBR, but recalls that she comes from the Marine Life Institute at Jewel of Morro Bay, California, which *is* 'across the ocean', on the West coast of America.

[image: Dory]
<sub>Disney Pixar’s eternal optimistic Dory (Finding Nemo; Finding Dory)</sub>

A [fun fact](https://www.livescience.com/55399-clownfish.html) is that Clown fish actually do live ([in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphiprioninae))
in Sea Anemones, in the GBR.

[image: Clownfish]
<sub>Clownfish make their homes near sea anemones, which protect them from predators. (Image credit: Aleksey Stemmer | Shutterstock)</sub>